# how to check if period sign(.) is removed from the word in textbox in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it is possible to hit an event if the period sign **`.`** is removed from textbox.
for example I have a textbox`#Quantity` which takes numeric values as input with period sign

[image]

and i have a drop down control`#unitValue` which have three option

I had successfully hit an event on period sign **`.`** key press as follows

```
$("#Quantity").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 46) {
        //successfully disabled Gram in Unit
    }
});
```

Now I want to enable "Gram" option in the drop down if the period sign **`.`** is removed from the textbox.
I have an idea but don't if it is right to do so.
Idea is:-
  On any key press add each letter to an array, Then on backspace key press, I check if the letter on the array index is period sign **`.`** or not if it is the  **`.`** sign then enable the "Gram"

Any help will be Appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Hi Need a bit more clarity

Comment: `onfocusout` check that textbox value have `.` or not. and set attribute to enable or disable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle** - *updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/a7btu2rb/1/)  -*using [**`.prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead*

```js
// attach the functionality on multi events
$('#inpt').on('keypress input change', function() {
  var Gram = $('#slct').children('[value="1"]');

  // if the indexOf "." is > -1, then there's a dot 
  if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') > -1) {

    // disable the Gram option
    Gram.prop('disabled', true);

    // ====================== this part was added by @SarathChandra 
    // reset the drop down if Gram option was selected
    if ($('#slct').val() === "1" || $('#slct').val() === null) {
      $('#slct').val("0");
    }
      // ====================== @SarathChandra Thank you for the improvement

  } else {

    // if it the dot was removed, we set the disabled prop to false
    Gram.prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inpt" type="text">
<select id="slct">
  <option value="0">- select -</option>
  <option value="1">Gram</option>
  <option value="2">Kilo</option>
  <option value="3">Quntal</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to [@SarathChandra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2869791/sarathchandra) added these couple lines:

```
if($('#slct').val() == "1" || $('#slct').val() == null){
      $('#slct').val("0");
}
```

To fix it when the entered value doesn't contain a **`.`**, and Gram was selected *THEN* period was add, it resets the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/evwLs5Lu/)

You could use this.

```js
$(document).on('keyup paste', '#Quantity', function() {        
  if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') > -1) {
    // disable the Gram option
    $('#Unit').children('[value="1"]').prop('disabled', true);
  } else{
    $('#Unit').children('[value="1"]').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Quantity" type="text">
    <select id="Unit">
      <option value="0">- select -</option>
      <option value="1">Gram</option>
      <option value="2">Kilo</option>
      <option value="3">Quntal</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing the previous entered text and compare it to the actual text in the Input:

```
...
var prevText = "";

$("#Quantity").keypress(function(e) {
    var actualText = $(e.target).text();
    if (this.prevText.indexOf(".") !== -1 && actualText.indexOf(".") === -1) {
       // deleted
    }

    this.prevText = actualText;
}); 
...
```